# SOCKS5 - Connection authentication

Tags: c, winapi, socks

I am trying to implement reverse SOCKS5 according to [RFC1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt). I have a relay server which runs passively waiting for connections from the SOCKS5 client which acts a proxy, and the the client which wants to use the tunnel.

**Legend**

Server (10.211.55.6) = Relay = PC 1 (send/recv)

Client_1 (10.211.55.10) = Proxy (running on another PC in my network)

Client_2 (10.211.55.8) = Tunneller (connecting from MaxThon Browser (since it allows SOCKS5 authentication))

**Execution flow**

1. Client_1 connects to Server on port 9444
2. Server finds an unused port and binds to it (lets say port 13451 is opened)
3. Client_2 connect to Server on port 13451
4. Server accepts the connection and now relays the traffic between Client_1 and Client_2
5. Client_2 sends the SOCKS5 protocol (according to RFC1928) requests to Client_1 relayed through Server
6. Client_1 authenticates and gets a CONNECT command to `https://dnsleaktest.com` and sends back a `status_ok` response
7. The packets from the webpage are received, and the webpage is loaded

**Problem**

8. Client_2 wants to connect to another webpage (lets take `https://packetstormsecurity.com` for example).

**Question**

Client_1 only receives a few packets from Client_2 such as `\x17\x3\x3` or `\x17\x3\x3\x1` (what do these bytes represent?). Does Client_1 have to go through the SOCKS5 authentication again, or how would it process the request to the new webpage?

**Side Notes**

A) After a while, the page that Client_2 requested from Client_1 returns `ERR_TIMED_OUT` in the browser, since Client_2 didn't get any response. But if its expecting a response, then its also assuming that I know how to parse the bytes that it sends, but I don't know what they are as I haven't seen them in the RFC1928 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Client_1 only receives a few packets from Client_2 such as \x17\x3\x3 or \x17\x3\x3\x1 (what do these bytes represent?).

Client_2 is requesting tunnels to HTTPS hosts.  What you are seeing are [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) packets between Client_2 and the HTTPS server, after the SOCKS tunnel to the HTTPS server has been established:

```
\x17 = content type (#23, application data)
\x03 = major version 3
\x03 = minor version 3
\x01 = fragment length (1 byte)
...
```

> Does Client_1 have to go through the SOCKS5 authentication again

Once a SOCKS tunnel has been established, everything that is transmitted through that tunnel is application-defined data.  As such, there is no way for a SOCKS client to send a new SOCKS command over an existing TCP connection.  That means Client_2 must create a new TCP connection to your Relay Server (and thus to Client_1) in order to request a new SOCKS tunnel to a different host, and that involves a new SOCKS authentication handshake, yes (even if SOCKS were not involved, Client_2 would have to establish a new TCP connection to the new host anyway).

> or how would it process the request to the new webpage?

Client_1 would have to wait to accept a new TCP connection from Client_2 (or any other client) before it could process a request for a new SOCKS tunnel.

> After a while, the page that Client_2 requested from Client_1 returns ERR_TIMED_OUT in the browser, since Client_2 didn't get any response.

Then either the HTTPS server is not responding to Client_2's HTTPS request, or more likely Client_1 has a logic bug in its handling of the SOCKS tunnel and is not relaying the HTTPS server's response data to Client_2.

> But if its expecting a response, then its also assuming that I know how to parse the bytes that it sends, but I don't know what they are as I haven't seen them in the RFC1928 documentation.

Once Client_1 has established a SOCKS tunnel, it is not supposed to parse anything transmitted through that tunnel (unless the SOCKS authentication scheme that you negotiated requires encapsulation of transmitted data).  Data transmitted through a SOCKS tunnel is application-defined, so only the client and target server on both ends of the tunnel know what the data actually is.  Client_1 must relay as-is (handling encapsulation if needed) whatever raw data it receives in both directions (just as your Relay Server does).

Comment: Thank you for answering all my questions, the final question in regards to your answer. How would Client_1 know that Client_2 is trying to access a new host? The reason is, I understand I can run another Client_1.exe and it would wait for another connection from Client_2 on the designated port to connect to a new host. But how would I automate this ...

Comment: "*How would Client_1 know that Client_2 is trying to access a new host?*" - because Client_2 would have to connect a new TCP connection to Client_1 (via your Relay Server) and then send a SOCKS `CONNECT` request over that new connection. Client_2 can't issue new SOCKS commands over a previous TCP connection.  I covered that in my answer. "*I can run another Client_1.exe and it would wait for another connection from Client_2*" - only if your Relay Server supports that.

Comment: But, the way I have my implementation now is, Client_2 connects to a port opened by the Relay, which is only opened when Client_1 connects to it. Does that mean that in order to get this right, I would have to close the existing socket on the Relay for the same port, and then re-open the port so that this connection would be re-initiated and then when Client_2 connects to it (when it requests a new host), it would resend the SOCKS command? "I can run another Client_1.exe and it would wait for another connection from Client_2" - My Relay Server supported multiple connections at one time, yes.

Comment: "*But how would I automate this*" - there is nothing really to automate. Client_2 decides when to make new TCP connections to the Relay Server, which then decides which Client_1 to relay to. Client_1 must handle SOCKS on a per-TCP-connection basis.

Comment: When Client_2 wants to connect to a new host, it must create a new TCP connection, period (it can leave a previous TCP connection open, ie when multiple tabs are open in Client_2's browser). A server socket can have multiple clients connected to it at a time.  So your Relay Server can (and should) have only 1 port open for multiple Client_2s to connect to. The Relay Server must keep track of which Client_2 connection is related to which Client_1 connection so it can relay data back and forth.  Same thing in Client_1 when it opens a tunnel to a requested server

Comment: My goal is to make this as easy for the user as possible. Thats why I am asking how I can make it so that the user doesn't have to configure a new port in his MaxThon browser every time he wants to connect to a new host.

Comment: The user MUST configure their browser to connect to a SOCKS proxy, you can't automate that. The browser will then make new TCP connections to the configured proxy as needed. The user would just have to specify your Relay Server as that proxy. The rest is handled  transparently between the browser and Relay Server, between Relay Server and Client_1, and between Client_1 and the target server - IF- you are managing your connections and relays correctly.  Which it sounds like you are not, if you are having troubles.

Comment: Your latest comment answered all my questions, so I should just run the port in step 2 in a new thread and when Client_2 connects to a new host, it would start a new connection sequence. Thanks for clearing it all up!!!